# Hide SXA filter checklist when no data is displayed

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using a SXA filter checklist with a SXA search results, I want to hide this filter when there is no data in the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily extend the search JS logic to do that. In one of your scripts, use `results-loaded` search event. When it will be triggered simply check number of results and in case there won't be any simply hide filter.

```
XA.component.search.vent.on("results-loaded", function (results) {
    //you custom logic here
});
```