# How to hide toggle filter based on search result item in SXA

Tags: sxa

I have created a search page using all SXA search components. How to hide toggle filter based on search result item in SXA. I want to show toggle filters only for some specific results, not for all results

Comment: This article may help you if you want to add a condition to hide a filter. Please refer to this. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12982/hide-sxa-filter-checklist-when-no-data-is-displayed